# ASP.NET VB web 3 capas al publicar la entidad no esta definida

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Buenas, estoy haciendo una aplicación web con vb.net en 3 capas. Tengo los proyectos de entidades, datos y negocio, y uno de aplicación web asp.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada proyecto tiene agregada la referencia de los otros, y en local no me da ningún error, pero al publicar me sale lo siguiente:

[image: Imagen de error]

Que me estoy dejando? Tengo que añadir alguna referencia más en algún sitio?
Gracias y un saludo.

Edit:

Más información del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las dlls se encuentran en la carpeta bin y las clases son públicas.

Comment: Prueba de seleccionar una dll del bin y en propiedades pon "copy local" a true.

Comment: No me da ninguna opción de copia, de hecho las dll están subidas al servidor dentro de la carpeta bin

Comment: donde es que publicas? lo haces en el IIS de la pc local o es en un hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, pues el problema era que mi aplicación dependía de otra aplicación superior, es decir, había una página maestra donde yo metía mi aplicación.

He copiado las dll en la carpeta bin que está por encima de mi aplicación, y funciona perfectamente.

Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas y las ideas.